# Реализация сервиса Google play game

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Не могу найти информацию как реализовать вход в игру по Google (play game), чтобы записывать количество очков и выводить в приложении рейтинг игроков. Подскажите, что почитать, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Читаем мануалы и смотрим исходники примеров:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart
https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks?hl=ru
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples